# What exactly is $k\left(T_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, terminology

Let $k$ be a field and $T_{n}$ indeterminates over $k$.
Is $k\left(T_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ the field of fractions of the form $x=\frac{p}{q}$, where $p\in k\left[T_{i}\right]_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $q\in k\left[T_{i}\right]_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\setminus\left\{ 0\right\} $
or is it something else, like a field of simple extensions?

Comment: Where did you encounter this notation? In what context? Many sources will use the same notation in completely different ways, so the more you can tell us about that, the more likely someone will be able to answer your question in a more definitive manner.

Comment: What are you talking about? What is the Integral domain here? What is $\;k\;$ ? What is $\;[T_i]_{i\in\Bbb N}\;$? Why not to define things?

Comment: So we're to guess that $\;k[T_i]_{i\in\Bbb N}\;$ is the ring of polynomials over some field in infinite unknowns?

Comment: Ookk...then yes: that's the field of fractions. Isn't it *always* defined that way for *any* integral domain?

Comment: @CameronBuie In a problem involving construction of the unique valuation $v$ of $k\left(T_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $\mathbb{Z}^{\left(\mathbb{N}\right)}$.

Comment: @Timbuc That's what I initially thought, but things did not stick further on, so I had to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $k[T_1,T_2,\dotsc]$ (which is an integral domain). It is in particular a field extension of $k$. When the adjoined elements are denoted by capital letters, one usually means variables. So $k(a,b)$ often means a field extension of $k$ in which $a,b$ may satisfy some relations, but $k(T_1,T_2)$ usually not.